# Number theory modulo problem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

**For a prime $p$, if $x^p \equiv y^p \pmod p $**

**Then prove that;
$x^p \equiv y^p(\bmod p^2) $**

Firstly I am confused where to approach to prove this question ,though i know several propositions and theorems related to congruences

Like by applying  fermat's theorem we can easily derive 
$x\equiv y \pmod p $
But what to do after that ?

Secondly i approached with the proposition that ,iff
$x \equiv y (\bmod n_i)$ And for $i=1,2$
Then 
$x \equiv y (\bmod [n_1,n_2]) $

But i am unable to prove the question with these two approaches

Please tell whether either of my approaches will help to prove the question if not then please give a proper proof with steps for the same

This is an olympiad book question(not a homework problem)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $\ x\equiv y \left(\hspace{-0.7em}\mod p\right)\ $, then $\ x= y + np\ $ for some integer $\ n\ $.  What happens if you you use the binomial theorem to expand $\ \left(y + np\right)^p\ $ in powers of $\ y\ $ and $\ np\ $?

Answer (score 1):

If $p=2$ then $x$ and $y$ have the same parity, hence the same quadratic residue $\pmod 4$. Otherwise p is odd, and

$$x^p-y^p=(x-y)\sum_{i=1}^{p}x^iy^{p-i-1}\equiv(x-y)\sum_{i=1}^{p}x^ix^{p-i-1}=(x-y)\sum_{i=1}^{p}x^{p-1}\equiv(x-y)\cdot p\cdot1 \equiv 0\pmod {p^2}$$

Comment: @DonAntonio thanks I've fixed it.